# rss fingerprint database

Tags: android, rssi, indoor-positioning-system

I am developing an indoor positioning app based on fingerprinting approach. I am stuck at the point where I should store the  wi-fi rss values in the database in the training phase. Since rss values vary significantly, will storing the absolute rss values lead to large errors in localization?

I have read many articles and http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy439/papers/WILL-pre.pdf says the absolute rss values of each AP varies but their difference relationship maintains. The author introduces a concept called Rss Stacking Difference which is the cumulative difference between one AP and all other APs. Can i store this Rss Stacking Difference in the database rather than absolute values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not try to collect several RSS from each reference node for each cell or interesting position (depends on how you segmented the map). That will mitigate the fluctuation of RSS values. then by taking the mean value for each reference node, you will have several mean values for each position or segment. Then you determine the position based on the minimum difference between the data sets in the database and the collected values in online mode.

let the position at point (x=100,y=120) associated with the following finger print
{mac1=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,rssaverage=-47.54 ; {mac2=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,rssaverage=-60.1 ; ...}
and the collected values in online mode will be structured in the same way and compared respectively.

I hope that can be helpful
good luck